# Parsing GeoJSON with nested properties using Python

Tags: python, geojson, json, parse

I do have a nice GeoJSON download. Unfortunately, the GeoJSON itself contains some strange key names which indicate, that "nesting" wasn't done right:

```json
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "datetime": "2023-09-02T11:23:39Z",
        "pers:omega": 44.970489,
        "pers:phi": -0.036297,
        "pers:kappa": -0.064188
        
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          12.07845612956043,
          55.61764618498095
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      }
    }]}
```

Is there a default way to split up the key names at the colons in the key names? Desired format:

```json
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "datetime": "2023-09-02T11:23:39Z",
        "pers": {"omega": 44.970489,
               "phi": -0.036297,
               "kappa": -0.064188
           }
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          12.07845612956043,
          55.61764618498095
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      }
    }]}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a pure Python problem. The result of `geojson.loads()` is a dictionary and your problem is not geospatial.

## One solution:

```py
# your FeatureCollection as a dictionary
geo = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "datetime": "2023-09-02T11:23:39Z",
        "pers:omega": 44.970489,
        "pers:phi": -0.036297,
        "pers:kappa": -0.064188
        
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          12.07845612956043,
          55.61764618498095
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      }
    }]}
```

I use here [`defaultdict()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/defaultdict-in-python/) to memorize the grouping keys (see [Python – Group Hierarchy Splits of keys in Dictionary](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-group-hierarachy-splits-of-keys-in-dictionary/))

```py
split_chr = "."
res = defaultdict(dict)
for key, val in geo['features'][0]['properties'].items():
  if splt_chr in key:
     ini_key, low_key = key.split(splt_chr)
     res[ini_key][low_key] = val
  else:
     res[key] = val

print(res)
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'datetime': '2023-09-02T11:23:39Z', 'pers': {'phi': -0.036297, 'kappa': -0.064188, 'omega': 44.970489}})

geo['features'][0]['properties'] = dict(res)
pprint(geo)

{'type': 'FeatureCollection',
  'features': [
    {
      'type': 'Feature',
      'properties': {
        'datetime': '2023-09-02T11:23:39Z',
        'pers': {'omega': 44.970489,
               'phi': -0.036297,
               'kappa': -0.064188
           }},
      'geometry': {
        'coordinates': [
          12.07845612956043,
          55.61764618498095
        ],
        'type': "Point"
      }
    }]}
```

Comment: '''def nest_properties(item):
    # unnest a json set using the delimieter ":"
    nested = {}
    for key, value in item['properties'].items():
        if ':' in key:
            prefix, sub_key = key.split(':', 1)
            if prefix not in nested:
                nested[prefix] = {}
            nested[prefix][sub_key] = value
        else:
            nested[key] = value
    return nested
for item in data['items']:
                item['properties'] = nest_properties(item)'''